# Wait for location and then execute retrofit call with rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

In my application I need to wait for the user location then execute a retrofit (when location is received).

I have the observable working

```
mlocationService.getLocation()
            .timeout(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(location -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "COORDS: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
            }, e -> Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()));
```

But now I need to call the second observable with the retrofit call, is there a better way than nesting the second observable inside the onNext() of the first one?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use the `flatmap` operator:

```
mlocationService.getLocation()
        .timeout(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .flatmap(location -> retrofitApi.getData(location))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...)
```

The subscription will now get the result of the retrofit call

If you need to return both the retrofit result and the location then you can use the zip operator:

```
mlocationService.getLocation()
        .timeout(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .flatmap(location -> Observable.zip(
            retrofitApi.getData(location),
            Observable.just(location),
            (Func2<Response<Data>, Location, ResponseLocation>) (response, location) -> {
                return new ResponseLocation(response, location)
            }
        ))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...)
```

Where ResponseLocation is just a class which takes a location and a retrofit result.  The subscription would then get a ResponseLocation as it's argument.

**EDIT**

To use the location before you call Retrofit just expand the lambda:

```
mlocationService.getLocation()
        .timeout(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .flatmap(location -> {
            updateMap(location);
            return retrofitApi.getData(location);
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot.

Comment: But now how can I access location? I need to update a map also with the new location.

Comment: You could use the zip operator to combine the location with the retrofit result.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I need to achieve is: get the location as soon as possible update the UI with the new location and then call retrofit. In your example, the app wait for both tasks complete then deliver the results.

Comment: Ah ok.  In that case you can just use the location in the flatmap before you call retrofit.  I'll update again

Comment: That's it, after your second edit a come to that solution but when I first tried for some reason it return a plain java object and not my POJO. Thank you for your solution. Cheers